# Do I need to be concerned about moisture around dryer exhaust?

Tags: dryer, ducts, exhaust-vent

I have a dryer stacked on top of my washer and the exhaust duct attachment point is elevated off the ground.

Or contractor had to build out the wall and create an area where the plumbing, gas and exhaust can be hooked up to my machines.

We've been running these machine for about 6 months and I just noticed that there is warm moist air flowing (low flow) around the duct connection point by the wall (red arrows in picture) there is also some condensation on the walls.

Should I be concerned about moist air getting behind the walls and causing mold?

Is there anything I can do to minimize the leaking moist air?

[image: duct connection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically unwrapped the tape and examine the connections at both ends. The flexible duct had a few holes and the tape seal at both ends were not good. I bought a new flexible duct and some 4" diameter screw on clamps for both ends. Now the condensation problem is gone.

[image: dryer vent clamps]
[image: clamped duct]

Answer (score 1):

I think your venting is leaking.  If it was not leaking, you would not be having condensation.  Condensation in this area is a result of warm moist air - from the dryer - contacting a cool surface.  Seal the leak, solve the problem.

I've been working on dryer professionally for 40 years.

Comment: Should I untape the joint and try to seal it better? How do I do that?  Use a zip tie around it? Then tape it?  Thank you.